# Cannot find Share definition

Tags: samba, shared-folders

Ubuntu 16.04: I am trying to start afresh with some Folder Shares so I removed them from the smb.conf file but one still persists and I can't find where it is defined in order to remove it. I tried the follwing and it shows the errant Share, but not where it is defined. I have also checked the Properties for the Folder in question and it shows as not shared.

```
net usershare info --long

[qrtShare]
path=/home/zenme/oldStuff
comment=
usershare_acl=Everyone:F,
guest_ok=y
```

Where is this Share defined and how do I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Net usershares are not defined in the `smb.conf` file.

To remove your share, it is actually quite easy with the following command:

```
net usershare delete qrtShare
```

That should clear that share out for you.

Hope this helps!